# Provide some method of breaking a tag synonymy

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

We will get tag synonyms created that should not have been, so there needs to be method that lets user say a tag synonym is wrong so a moderator can look at it.

Something like

- You can vote to say a synonym is wrong
- If more than n people says a given tag synonymy is wrong than a moderator looks at it.

Being able to add comments to the tag info page would be a good start.

Comment: Would a flagging functionality not suffice?

Comment: @Ladybug, how do you flag a tag?

Comment: @Ian, you can't now, but this functionality could be added to the tag synonyms page. I don't think you need several people to vote on it.

Comment: @Ladybug, actually, voting might work better; any given bad flag might be for a topic that one or more mods aren't familiar with.

Comment: are we trying to fix a theoretical problem or an actual problem?

Comment: @waffles I haven't really been using the tag synonym feature but there have been reports on Meta of synonyms that needed to be decoupled.

Answer (score 1):

Raise the specific synonym on meta if its broken.

I will wipe out synonyms if they are wrong. I will also raise the pre-reqs for approval (4 upvotes) if stuff is consistently wrong.

Comment: Is this something that could / should be delegated to trusted users? I'm looking to clean up some of the tags on the Apple site and it looks like I'll have to chat with the moderators or ask there for edits in that site's meta...